# Counting the number of used cells in a column next to a found String

Tags: excel, vba

Here is a reference pic to help show what i'm talking about.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/RKEDi.jpg

In my `For Next` loop I have the following code.

```
Dim Counter As Long

For Counter = 0 To ActiveSheet.Rows(1).Cells.Find("QQQ").Offset(0, 1).End(xlUp).Row
```

This is suppose to look through Row 1 until it finds "QQQ" and count the number off used cells in the column to the immediate right.  I'm not sure how to tell excel how to `Count` the offset column.

The reason I use the `Find` is because each of the sheets has a different column that the criteria will be in.  For example: in the pic above The column happens to be Q.  It could be different based on the sheet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Dim Counter As Long

With ActiveSheet
    For Counter = 0 To .Cells(.Rows.Count, .Rows(1).Cells.Find("QQQ").Offset(,1).Column).End(xlUp).Row
    ' rest of your counter loop code


End With
```

Comment: Appears to have worked.  There are other problems than this.  Just so that everyone knows that happens to stumble onto this post.  `For Counter = 0 To ActiveSheet.Cells(ActiveSheet.Rows.Count, ActiveSheet.Rows(1).Cells.Find("QQQ").Offset(0, 1).Column).End(xlUp).Row`  Make sure you add the `ActiveSheet` like so.  Thanks.

Comment: All those "ActiveSheet"s can be avoided if you use the "With ActiveSheet ... End With" block like in my answer.